# Java Code Conventions disappeared (where to find)

Tags: java

Well, look here, please: [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)
There is nothing to download or view there. I mean, if you try to download anything, you'll get this: "We're sorry, the page you requested was not found.".
Could you help me find these conventions. I mean exactly these ones, not any other.
These conventions are likely to be found somewhere on the Internet. I can't find, maybe you can. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wow, that's indeed unexpected!

Comment: A lot of things disappeared in the Oracle takeover. File a bug report.

Comment: It was around for a while, they had reformatted the pages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Internet Archive [seems to have a version](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http:/www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) that was [captured in its entirety on 22 Feb 2014](https://web.archive.org/web/20140116202009/http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html). Note that the revision date of the document, as of now, is 20 Apr 1999.

Some of the conventions have been labeled obsolete or unhelpful. As [Tomasz Nurkiewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/605744/tomasz-nurkiewicz) writes in the editorial preface of ["Java Coding Conventions considered harmful"](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/java-coding-conventions-considered-harmful.html):

> You would expect this 20+ pages document to be the most complete, comprehensive and authoritative source of good practices, hints and tips with regards to the Java language. But once you start to read it, disappointment followed by frustration and anger increases. I would like to point out the most obvious mistakes, bad practices, poor and outdated advices given in this guide. In case you are a Java beginner, just forget about this tutorial and look for better and more up-to-date reference materials.

Comment: Ironically, your link ([*seems to have a version](https://web.archive.org/web/%2a/http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)*) is dead... great job finding the stuff, though ;)

Comment: There were plenty of undesirable things in the JCC, but that blog post you linked to seems to almost exclusively identify all the wrong things for the wrong reasons (e.g. the 80 column limit isn't *harmful*, per se, and is actually fairly useful in certain environments; most of the blog author's points were due to conflicting personal style choices rather than legitimate bad consequences -- some reasonable points, but not authoritative). +1 good find in the archive though, I had trouble locating it on a cursory search there.

Comment: @ccjmne: Oddly enough, the Markdown source is correct, but Markdown seems to dislike archive.org's `*` in the URL, and archive.org dislikes parsing the `%2a` in the URL. Working on a way for them to play nice; maybe that's a good SO question in the making!

Comment: @JeffBowman That *is* weird. I've edited your post to run the URL through bit.ly.

Comment: @JasonC: Thanks for the link fix. Regarding the blog post, in the name of balance, I'm just trying to offer an overview of _some_ criticism in case the next person using SO to find a good link has less-specific needs. Style guides and criticisms thereof are both "personal style choices" by definition. :)

Comment: I understand that the critique that you linked to is by @TomaszNurkiewicz.  Worth giving the man some credit.  It's a good piece of writing.  My favourite part was the bit about `cp` being a good name for a `char` pointer - even if we had a `char *` type, `cp` would be a terrible name for one of them.

Comment: Fair enough. Was hoping the live link was credit enough, but I'll add an explicit name and link to SO. FWIW, "@Name" links are [pretty limited in their functionality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).